# (1) Constant Current and (2) Zero Voltage

Tags: voltage, current

I received power data from groundwater pumps we are currently investigating. However, I have trouble finding out what the issue is in two data sets. I cannot figure out if there is a hardware problem in the meter or something wrong with the power supply itself. Googling various topics didn't help either. My background is only a physics class at university (environmental engineering).

Data1: What I don't understand is that phase C features a nearly constant current over time even though the ones for phase A and B vary and are of similar magnitude. I am interested in the total power and I think this leads to an underestimate.[image]

Data2: How can the voltage of phase A be zero but the power not? And for the line voltages, if phase A features zero voltage, shouldn't phase BC be the only one with a line voltage of around 424 (instead of CA)?[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I am not going to open any random stuff in a dropbox. Also when that link becomes unavailable, the question becomes meaningless. I imagine those are graphs, so insert images of them into the question.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I peeped - they are spreadsheets - hundreds and hundreds of numbers

Comment: Well it's my folder, so it won't become unavailable soon :) yes, two spreadsheets. If they were graphs I would have inserted them.
@JImDearden it ain't that bad...

Comment: @user148966: soon? what does that mean? in a month? in a year? in 5 years? 10?

Comment: if I get constructive comments a long time, otherwise not so long

Comment: @user148966: see, and that is the problem. Ever read the tour? "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about electronics design." This question will be totally meaningless after you removed that stuff for future visitors.

Comment: @PlasmaHH well where should I upload it to then?

Comment: Screenshot the important part of the datasheet and post it as an image in your post.

Comment: @user148966: If its a small list of numbers, put it into the question. If a graph is more suitable, make it a graph.

Comment: @winny thanks, sorry I thought a file might be easier, stockexchange first-timer, my bad...

Comment: I think you could post a small sample here in your question.  And link to the complete set in CSV or some other plain text format.